# iPhone app enterprise distribution

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a query regarding the enterprise distribution.

Can I load/build multiple apps using a single enterprise distribution profile?

i am developing multiple applications for an organization, they wants to distribute the applications inHouse [enterprise distribution].They are in a process of getting the enterprise distribution licence.

can anyone please let me know whether loading multiple applications using a single enterprise distribution certificate is possible or not?

Comment: i am looking for some tutorial or steps to deploy enterprise iPhone app, also I wanted to know that in house app can be distribute to company employees but is it possible for customers too with $299 enterprise certificate thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write and distribute (in-house) as many enterprise as you can manage. You just will not be able to distribute them in the iTunes AppStore.

Comment: ok, i got confused with 1st answer...because he gave that "we have developed and distributed over 7 apps on App store".

Comment: using a single 299$ licence it is possible rite?

Comment: No, the enterprise license does not allow for AppStore distribution, only the $99 (Standard) license does.

Comment: i dont want to distribute via appstore, we are developing multiple applications for an organization and we want to distribute inHouse.is it possible with a single 299$ distribution licence or do we need to take individual 299$ licence for each application?

Comment: I got that from your question. All you need is the 1 (enterprise) license to distribute ALL of your apps within your organization.

Comment: is it required that company should have "DUNS" number to get this licence? can you please share me where can i find the exact information and procedure to get this?

Comment: You must be a company or organization with a DUNS number to apply. Says on the front page of http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: If you are still in doubt, that page also says, to clarify,  "Distribute Your In-house APPS" and "Test on iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch".

Answer (score -1):

Yes of course it is possible. I also work in a company which has an enterprise distribution certificate and we have developed and distributed over 7 apps on App store.So go ahead and distribute as many apps as you can!

Cheers.

Comment: hi aditya, i am not talking about the distribution through app store.we need to distribute the application inHouse [without app store] using enterprise distribution certificate. using this can we build multiple applications?

Comment: What do you mean by distributing in house? You can install your certificate on multiple PCs and then you can install the App from any PC having that Certificate.

Comment: we can distribute the application via 3 ways rite...ad-hoc (for testing), enterprise distribution (for an organization) and via appstore.i want to implement via enterprise distribution for multiple apps. you are talking about the appstore rite?